Not adding om and namah to a mantra
What will the effect of the mantra if the om and namah are removed from the ashttotara namavali or any nama mantra of a deity?
Will it affect the mantra if om and namah is removed from the mantra? Suppose I remove the om and namah from the om namah shivai will I not get the proper effect of the mantra?
I would like to give you an example of my own practice - As a Nitya upasaka I chant the ashttotara shatanama of Sri Saraswati. Now every nama of the deity is sandwiched between om and namah. Now what will happen if I chant just the nama and not the om and namah. Will I get any effect from the mantra or will it be effectless?

@SpiritualSeeker no I am note getting the answer I want.

Ashtotara Sata Nāmāvali and Sahasra Nāmāvali will always have Om(ॐ) and Namah(नमः) syllables.
Om(ॐ): This is pranava mantra, a sacred syllable in Hinduism that has multiple meaning. From this primeval sound emanates every other sound. In the present context, this symbol simply indicates the presence of Devatha/God.
Namah(नमः): The word holds profound spiritual and devotional significance such as Surrender and Salutation. The primary meaning is to bow, Salute or offer reverence.
I) Your first question What will the effect of the mantra if the om and namah are removed from the ashttotara namavali or any nama mantra of a deity?
If Oh and Namah are removed then what is left out is just a name that does not convey 'the presence of God' and 'Surrender/Salutation' respectively!
II) Your second question Will it affect the mantra if om and namah is removed from the mantra? Suppose I remove the om and namah from the om namah shivai will I not get the proper effect of the mantra?
Removal of Oh and Namah will leave a name alone which has no effect.
Suppose from Om Namah Shivai(ॐ नमः शिवाय), the removal of Oh and Namah will leave Shivai(शिवाय) alone which becomes a mere name without associating any reverence or surrender.
III) Your third and final question I would like to give you an example of my own practice - As a Nitya upasaka....any effect from the mantra or will it be effectless?
Yes, it is completely futile.

without om and Namah, it’s Nama. Nama Japa also have spiritual value right ?

@SpiritualSeeker the question is not about Nama Japa, but it is about removing Om and Namah from Ashtotara Sata Nāmāvali resulting in 108 distinct names.
